# List the members of a Facebook group via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is is possible to list the members of a Facebook group using the Facebook API? If yes, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes - use the members connection.  Check out the [Group reference](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group) on the [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

Comment: Should you be the group owner ? Does it work for every group ?

Comment: I don't think you have to be an admin.  It is restricted to public groups or groups that you are a member of.  Check out the Permissions section in that link.

Comment: It will give only 5000 members... any other solution?

Comment: @waqasalieee you mean 5000 per call or among all pages?  If there's a "next" field in your result, that is the next page of data.

Comment: @NG. Is it also possible to retrieve the list of pending member requests and then send them a message?

Answer (score 22):

[This is no longer possible:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/group/members)

> This edge was deprecated on April 4th, 2018, and can no longer be used.

Comment: Fallout from the [2018 Facebook databreach and presidential election](https://www.google.com/search?q=facebook+data+breach+presidential+elections) I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

First you need an access token. I'd recommend this article:

http://benbiddington.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/facebook-graph-api-getting-access-tokens/

If you want a permanent access token you must ask for the "offline_access" extended permission on getting it.

After that, it's just a matter of issuing a REST API call:

https://graph.facebook.com/[GROUPID]/members?access_token=[ACCESSTOKEN]

and you'll receive a JSON list of all the members of that group. Very handy!

Answer (score 1):

```
 Request request = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
                groupId+"/members", bundle,
                HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {}
Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Comment: *＋1* for providing the code rather than a link-only answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the members link on

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group

If you click on that link it will generate a oauth token for you, then simply substitute the groupid

It will only return 500 members though