# How to get the list of all groups I'm member of, with Facebook API?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I know it's no longer to get a list of users of a given Facebook group, see [List the members of a Facebook group via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087227/list-the-members-of-a-facebook-group-via-api).

But how can I get a list of all Facebook groups I'm member of?

Possibly, with the number of members? Something like:

```
Group ABC     30k members
Group DEF     5k members
Group GHI     40 members
```

How to do this with Facebook API, with Python?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups/, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v12.0/group#readfields

Comment: @CBroe For the first, I see something like "This document refers to a feature that was removed after API of graph v3.2." Does it still work, until when?

Comment: Doesn't show that for me. Short test in Graph API Explorer seems to indicate it still works fine with v12.0

Comment: @CBroe Here some answers show it's deprecated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472864/how-to-get-the-list-of-facebook-groups-using-graph-api

Comment: @CBroe Did you require the `user_groups` permission? I can't even add this in the app settings.

Comment: @CBroe Maybe can you post a sample code answer (in Python or PHP), showing how you achieved to do it? Here it returns an empty list, like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472864/how-to-get-the-list-of-facebook-groups-using-graph-api

Comment: I have one app for which it is currently working, and it is definitively showing me groups I am not an admin of. That app still had the `groups_show_list` permission from earlier, but I can't even find that one documented any more. So it might indeed be, that this is not possible any more.

Comment: @CBroe Maybe I'm looking at the wrong place, can you share a screenshot where you can add / remove `groups_show_list`? Also, are you using `v12.0` and which graph version, where to see which graph version I'm using? 3.2, 2.3, 2.4, etc.

Comment: Like I said, it was an app that had that permission granted earlier already. I can remove and add it again for that app (directly with GAE), but not for others, it doesn't show in the list for those, when I start to type the permission name. Couldn't tell you what factors this depends on, sorry.

Comment: Maybe you can post this last comment as an answer, it might be helpful for others, for future reference ; I'll accept your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is no more available in the latest version of the Facebook API, as seen in also [How to get the list of facebook groups using graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472864/how-to-get-the-list-of-facebook-groups-using-graph-api).

It is still possible for apps created before the change of the API, see @CBroe's comments.